# Number Theory relating Perfect Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all the possible positive integral values of $n$ for which $n+9$, $16n+9$ and $27n+9$ are all perfect squares.  I didn't work on it as I have no idea on how to approach such question.  I only found $n=0$ to satisfy the condition but its not positive integer.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't think for any appropriate title

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea of such question? What should my approach or how should i approach?

Comment: maybe think modulo 9? The problem seems to be hinting at this. I will try and think.

Comment: Factoring the last equation might give you some insight. Enough to write a little more in the question anyway.

Comment: If $n=x^2-9$ then $16n+9=16x^2-135$. We are down to a finite list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start you off:

If $n + 9 = x^2$ and $16 n + 9 = y^2$, then $(4 x - y)(4 x + y) = 16 x^2 - y^2 = \ldots$.

Comment: Still i didn't get that Robert Sir

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $16$ and subtract the second.  What do you get?